# Blocking hack attempts

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2

I need some help.

I am seeing a lot of attempted logins in my Security Log.

This is a fairly new Godaddy VPS Server running Windows 2008 R2.

The attends are with various user IDs, that do repeat.

### The log entry looks like this:

Log Name:      Security
Source:        Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing
Date:          8/23/2019 5:43:31 PM
Event ID:      4625
Task Category: Logon
Level:         Information
Keywords:      Audit Failure
User:          N/A
Computer:      s132-148-82-95.secureserver.net
Description:
An account failed to log on.

Subject:
    Security ID:        NULL SID
    Account Name:       -
    Account Domain:     -
    Logon ID:       0x0

Logon Type:         3

Account For Which Logon Failed:
    Security ID:        NULL SID
    Account Name:       Administrator
    Account Domain:

Failure Information:
    Failure Reason:     Unknown user name or bad password.
    Status:         0xc000006d
    Sub Status:     0xc000006a

Process Information:
    Caller Process ID:  0x0
    Caller Process Name:    -

Network Information:
    Workstation Name:   MSTSC
    Source Network Address: -
    Source Port:        -

Detailed Authentication Information:
    Logon Process:      NtLmSsp 
    Authentication Package: NTLM
    Transited Services: -
    Package Name (NTLM only):   -
    Key Length:     0

### This event is generated when a logon request fails. It is generated on the computer where access was attempted.

As you can see it doesn't give a caiier IP address.

And Microsoft says NTLM is not tied to any port.

I have tried blocking ports on TCP 1-79, 81-3388, 3390-20000, and in UDP 1-20000 in the firewall. But that doesn't stop the attempts.

I RDP into the server and it's only allowed from my IP address in the firewall.

Help.

I don't know what to try next.

Should I ever try to block them or should I just ignore them?

Gary

Comment: Servers facing the Internet tends to get login attempts. Bigger problem here is that the support for 2008 R2 will end in January 2020. It's time to upgrade.

Comment: Logon Type 3 is a network logon BUT it is not a remote interactive logon, which means that these are not logon attempts via RDP. Do you have IIS installed on this server? Do you have any other web platform installed? What are you using this server for and what are you exposing it to the internet for? HTTP, SMTP, FTP, etc.? See these articles for more info. - https://www.ultimatewindowssecurity.com/securitylog/encyclopedia/event.aspx?eventid=4625 - https://www.ultimatewindowssecurity.com/securitylog/book/page.aspx?spid=chapter3

Comment: Yes IIS is installed. And no other web service.  I have tried blocking port 80 but that didn't change much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you 100% sure RDP is being restricted by IP at the firewall? My first impression would be that login attempts are being made to your server via RDP. You really need to check which ports are open and publicly accessible.

One way to do this is to launch a web browser on the server, go to [GRC.com](https://www.grc.com), click the **Services** menu and choose **ShieldsUp!**. At the next page, click the **Proceed** button. On the page that opens, find the **ShieldsUp Services** box where you can scan your server’s ports. Definitely use the **Common Ports** and **All Service Ports** buttons. Additionally enter **3389** into the input box and click **User Specified Custom Port Probe**. This will check to see if RDP is open and publicly accessible.

I would also recommend that on the firewall you block all incoming connections to all ports and then selectively open ports to your requirements. Make sure you don’t block yourself out of your own server when you do this!

Hopefully following these steps will end the unauthorised login attempts. Good luck!

Comment: I'll try grc. I have tried with port 3389 as the only port open and that didn't help. And port 3389 is restricted in the firewall to only my ip address. And I know this works as someone was trying to rdp in to help me and they couldn't.

Comment: I performed a port scan of your server (assuming IP address 132.148.82.95) and you have ports 80,2383,3306,3389 open). A scan from a public IP, should only reveal 80. 3306 is MySQL and generally should not be publicly accessible. Any security vulnerabilities in MySQL which you haven’t patched could mean an attacker could get into MySQL. You also have RDP (3389) open which should be closed if your IP is the only one whitelisted.

Comment: 9876 is also open

Comment: Yes, that is the up. In don't understand why you see 3389 open as that is restricted to my ip. The other ports seem to indicate that Windows firewall isn't working the way I thought.

Comment: I have a rule in the Firewall: Enabled=Yes; Action=Block; Ports=1-79, 81-3388, 3390-20000. I don't understand why this isn't blocking those ports.

Comment: I am assuming I was scanning the correct server (132.148.82.95). If it is correct, use GRC to double check this for yourself. Do a custom scan of port 3389 and also that MySQL port I mentioned. Remember to run it from a web browser on the server. If you did it from your own PC/laptop, it would be checking your PC/laptop not the server. Obvious, but I thought I should mention it! What firewall are you using, is it Windows Firewall or is it GoDaddy’s own?

Comment: Yes correct server. I wasn't sure what tool on GRC to use. I tried it and got the same results. Yesterday I tried t1shopper and got the same results as you. I am using the Windows Firewall. It looks like the Windows Firewall doesn't work so good. I have turned all the rules that are active to block, except 80 and 3389. For 3389 that is set to only allow connections from my IP address. And the other rule I mentioned that blocks all ports from 1-20000 except 80 and 3389 is in there. Maybe I should get another firewall?

Comment: Although Windows firewall is not ideal, it is reliable. A hardware firewall is preferable, but GoDaddy would charge a fair bit extra for it, if they even offer it as an option. Regarding GRC, I gave you specific instructions in an earlier comment.

Comment: Wait a second. I ran GRC Shields Up and got the same results. The problem now is how to get the firewall to do what we want. I looked a bit and didn't see any software firewalls for servers.

Comment: in my opinion Windows firewall is the preferred software firewall. I would check to ensure you have no overlapping rules. You might have one rule denyjng access and another allowing. In this scenario the allow rule takes precedence.

Comment: This guide might help you secure your server with Windows Firewall. https://www.itprotoday.com/windows-server/windows-server-2008-r2-firewall-security

Comment: I'll check that out. Yes there are overlapping rules. They are all block. HTTP and RDP are pass through. But when I added HTTP to my block rule it blocked. Even with the allow rule. Btw the RDP allow rule has only my IP address as the remote address.

Comment: Ok, I deleted all inbound rules that I'm not using. Tat didn't change much. It did allow more open ports.

Comment: Now I don't understand a couple of things. One is I was poking around to see anything and found in the firewall settings it was turned off. I didn't turn it off. It must have been off when Godaddy set it up. Two is, if it was off why did changing to rules affect things. I'm rerunning a port scan now. The hacks seem to have stopped.

Comment: Not sure why it was turned off, but is sounds like you are getting somewhere!

Comment: Just scanned your server from ports 1-5000, the only port open is 80. I think your issue is fixed!

Comment: If your issue has been fixed, don’t forget to mark your question in Server Fault as solved. Otherwise it will continue to be shown as unsolved.

Answer (score 0):

Use wail2ban. It's like fail2ban but for windows
https://github.com/glasnt/wail2ban here is the link for the project. But it seems like the development has stopped for it. If I find any better alternatives to fail2ban, I will update my answer. In the meantime, definitely try wail2ban. It will temporarily block IP Addresses of failed login attempts after 5 failed attempts for 10 mins (the conditions, bantime etc can be changed). Don't forget to whitelist your own IP because by mistake if you enter your password wrong 5 times, you will get yourself banned for 10 mins (Default bantime set in wail2ban)

Comment: I'll check out wail2ban. Does it list the failed attempts do I can block them?

Comment: Yes you can and also you can add IPs to the block list manually

Comment: wail2ban seems to be archived and no longer usable.

Comment: try win2ban. I believe its same as wail2ban